# Es posible crear un elemento <nav> en html que sea global para todos los archivos html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

La cuestión es la siguiente, quiero hacer una pagina web implementando html, css y js.
La incógnita radica en que quiero hacer una área de nav como se ve a continuación:
[image]

Un elemento nav como el pie de pagina donde se encuentre el logo, una barra de búsqueda, etc.
Aquí va la duda, es posible hacer un script global para todos los archivos html, es decir, crear un solo elemento nav en un archivo independiente y que este se pueda repartir a los otros archivos existentes, de modo que no tenga que repetir codigo. Mas o menos como la herencia en Java, pero en este caso usando html, css y js.
De ser posible como se puede implementar ?
Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Sí, es posible. Investigá qué podés utilizar para el backend.

Comment: Y que has intentado? Porque con un import en PHP ya tienes el menú donde quieras. Yo uso un solo Menú, un solo Header y un solo Footer para mis sistemas

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo. Te dejo las dos mejores formas usando html y php:

## Método 1: Usar HTML

Código:

1. Crea un nuevo archivo llamado `navbar.html`
2. En él, pon el código de tu barra de navegación
3. En tu archivo principal HTML, inserta el código siguiente:

   ```
    <iframe src="./navbar.html/" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
   ```
4. Ya tienes tu navbar implementado.

## Método 2: Usar PHP (más fácil)

1. Crea un nuevo archivo llamado `index.php`.
2. Crea otro archivo llamado `navbar.php`
3. En tu archivo `index.php` inserta el siguiente código:

   ```
    include 'navbar.php';
   ```
4. En tu `navbar.php` pon:

   ```
    echo "[tu código aqui]";
   ```
5. Asegurate de reemplazar en tu `navbar.php` `tu código aqui` por tu codigo